# Where is this async function getting the request properties from?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

```
async function process(req, res) {
    try {
        const fileId = req.body.fileId;
        const batchIds = req.body.batchIds;
        const user = req.body.user;

        if (!fileId || !batchIds || !user) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                ok: false,
                message: `Batch Process Failed`
            });
        }

        const results = await processHelper.process(fileId, batchIds, user.mail);

        res.status(200).send({
            ok: true,
            results: results
        });
      } catch (error) {
          return res.status(400).send({
                ok: false,
                message: error.message
          });
      }
}
```

In this async/await function, it receives an asynchronous request to process some data from Express routes which is shown below:

```
const appRoutes = (app) => {
    app.post('/upload', uploadConfig.any(), document.upload);
    app.post('/process', document.process);
    app.get('/getFiles', document.getFiles);
    app.get('/getBatches/:fileId', document.getBatches);
};
```

What I'm confused by is the request properties it accesses like `req.body.fileId`, `req.body.batchIds`, and `req.body.user`. I'm a beginner Javascript programmer and I don't know where else in the code that it could be sending a request parameter with object properties. The actual call of the appRoutes arrow function is done in app.js:

```
routes.appRoutes(app);
```

Comment: From http post and get requests.

Comment: When someone makes a request to any of those routes, your process function is being called with the original request object and a response object, that is where they come from.

Comment: Express is an HTTP server framework, so the framework automatically calls the functions you've defined whenever HTTP requests are received over the TCP socket that the server opens with `app.listen()`.

Comment: In this program it's a http post request sent when the user uploads and processes a file. Does that mean it's accessing the file's data as if it was an object with object properties?

Comment: What do you mean by "*it receives an asynchronous request*"?

Comment: @DavidLin Yes, express does parse the HTTP POST text body into an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This props are defined by express. It creates request and response objects, then prepares a queue of middleware (including url handlers) and call them one by one passing those objects as arguments. It's very simple and straight-forward. :)